# Is there a way I can write a string into a FILE?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to write a string into a file, but I don't know how to do it, I have tried to use `wstring` instead of `string` in my randomString() string function, and other things just to write a string to a file.

The `if` condition is checking if file is created, and if yes, write to it.

`fopen` is used to open the file, `path1` variable is the path to my file, and the `"w"` is equal to write.

randomString() is a string function.

```
char buffer[100] = { randomString() };

FILE* file;

file = fopen(path1, "w");

if (file) {

    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), file);
    fclose(file);
}

return;
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/). There's an example of using `fwrite` with a char array. Also, you seem to have the `size` and `count` parameters backwards. Also, you don't assign `data` any values, you just allocate the array, so what you get is (sort of) random.

Comment: Do you want to write to a *text* file or a *binary* file? How do you want the string to be represented? After all, a character string is - in binary - just a sequence of numbers.

Comment: @JaMiT That you don't need to take care of this part anymore, but if you want to, I removed it.

Comment: @Mr.Strings Ah... OK, I might understand now. I think you meant "Is not important anymore", not "does".

Comment: @JaMiT Yeah, my English is bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to print out to a file the contents of a string, using `fwrite`, then you need to do something like the following

```
std::string str = randomString();

if ( file ) {
    fwrite( str.c_str(), sizeof( char ), str.size(), file );
    fclose( file );
}
```

Since `fwrite` expects the first parameter to be `void *`, an `std::string` is not compatible; however, a `char *` is. By calling `.c_str()` on the string, you would have a `char *` to work with. The second parameter is the size of the type, which for a `std::string` is `char`, so `sizeof( char )` gives the size (which is 1). The third parameter is the count (number of characters to write), which can easily be gotten from `str.size()`.

Comment: Great answer, ChrisMM, I have understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a new-ish compiler you can try [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    auto directoryToWriteTo = fs::current_path(); // returns a fs::path object
    std::ofstream fileStream(directoryToWriteTo.string() + "/nameOfYourFile.txt");
    if(fileStream.is_open())
        fileStream << "Whatever string you want to write to a file\n";
}
```

`std::filesystem` isn't needed for writing to one file, but it does make things like iterating over all files in a directory easy, [as adapted from the cppreference.com examples.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    auto directoryToTraverse = fs::current_path();
    for(auto& p: fs::directory_iterator(directoryToTraverse)){
        if(fs::is_regular_file(p)){
            std::ofstream tmpStream(p,std::ios_base::app); //open file in append mode
            tmpStream << "Append a string to each regular file in your directory\n";
        }
    }
}
```

It also allows one to change file permissions programmatically with standard c++.

Comment: Can you show how would you use `filesystem` to write to a file?